# Graph API - Ask user for login if logged out before publishing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website, where I have a custom button where my visitors can click the button and the Facebook Graph API is used to publish the image with a message to that user's Facebook page.

However, if the user is not logged in, the Graph API just throws an authentication error. How can I have Facebook's typical popup window open on my page that asks the user to login to Facebook? Then it probably needs to ask for permissions as well, right?

I understand how to use the `FB.login()` method, but I'm not sure if that is only used if you want to add a Facebook login button to your page (which is not what I want to do).

Comment: How do you perform a Graph API call?

Answer (score 0):

[FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) should give you the values you need in order to determine whether the user is logged in and authorized, unauthorized, or just not logged in. The values (retrieved from [the JavaScript SDK docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)) are as follows:

> 1. the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your application (connected)
> 2. the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application (not_authorized)
> 3. the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)

Comment: Thanks. If the user is not logged in, how do I instantiate the login dialog to popup?

Comment: Check out the example [in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/).. In the `else if` and `else` blocks, you can invoke `FB.login()` to popup the login dialog. Let me know if that makes sense..

Comment: Do you know anything about `FB.getLoginStatus()` not potentially being  accurate after the page loads? For example, load page, then `FB.init()`, then `FB.getLoginStatus()` and it shows `connected`. Then switch to browser tab with Facebook and logout. Then go back to your app tab, without refreshing page, do `FB.getLoginStatus()` again and it still shows you are connected. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Ah nevermind, figured it out: `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){},true);`. Thanks for the help